# AngularJs tables inside ng-repeat change values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a table using AngularJs: everything is working fine but when the json returns values like 0 or 1 I would like to be able to change them in Yes or No values, just inside the table. But I have no idea of how I can do it.

Here you can see my simplified code:

```
    <!-- /.panel -->
    <div class="panel panel-default" >
        <div class="panel-heading">

        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="table">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped dataTable no-footer" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc">
                            <tr role = "row" class="info text-center">
                                <th ng-click="order('msisdn')">Número Teléfono</th>
                                <th ng-click="order('icc')">ICC</th>
                                <th ng-click="order('imei')">IMEI</th>
                                <!--th>IMEI</th-->
                                <th ng-click="order('ActivationStatus')">Estado</th>
                                <th ng-click="order('sitename')">Instalación</th>
                                <th ng-click="order('siteaddress')">Dirección</th>
                                <th ng-click="order('sitecity')">Ciudad</th>
                                <th ng-click="order('sitezip')">Código Postal</th>
                                <th ng-click="order('comments')">Comentario</th>
                                <th ng-click="order('phonedesc')">Modelo Teléfono</th>
                                <th ng-click="order('ContractingMode')">VBP</th>


                            </tr>


                            <tr class=" text-center" ng-repeat-start="object in objects | filter:searchText | filter:tableFilter | orderBy:predicate:reverse" ng-click="main.activeRow = object.icc" >
                                <td>{{object.msisdn}}</td>
                                <td>{{object.icc}}</td>
                                <td>{{object.imei}}</td>
                                <td>{{object.ActivationStatus}}</td>
                                <td>{{object.sitename}}</td>
                                <td>{{object.siteaddress}}</td>
                                <td>{{object.sitecity}}</td>
                                <td>{{object.sitezip}}</td>
                                <td>{{object.comments}}</td>
                                <td>{{object.phonedesc}}</td>
                                <td>{{object.ContractingMode = 0}}</td>





                            </tr>

                            <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="main.activeRow==object.icc">
                                <td colspan="3"> <a>Fecha Activación:</a> <div> {{object.DateActivation}}</div> <div><a> Fecha Baja</a> {{object.DateDisconnection}}</div> <div><a> Último Evento HW</a> {{object.LastHWEvent}}</div></td>
                                <td colspan="4"> <a>Último Evento Humano:</a> <div> {{object.LastHumanEvent}}</div> <div><a> Último Evento Test</a> {{object.LastTestEvent}}</div></td>
                                <td> <button>Editar</button></td>
                            </tr>




                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.table-responsive -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-4 (nested) -->

                <!-- /.col-lg-8 (nested) -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-body -->
    </div>

    <!-- /.panel -->
```

And here there is the JavaScript

```
 angular.module('dashboard',[]);
function mainController($scope, $http, $filter) {
    $scope.objects=[{}];
    $scope.objects={};
    $scope.objects=[];
    $scope.grupos =[{}];
    $scope.longitud =[{}];
    var URL = "http://localhost:81/api/auth/logout";
    var URLOperation ="http://localhost:81/api/sites";

    $scope.getgrupos = function () {
        $http.get(URLOperation)
            .success(function (data) {
                var groups = data;

                angular.forEach(groups, function(group) {
                    var group2 = group;

                    angular.forEach(group2.sites, function(group3){

                        $scope.longitud.push(group3);

                    })


                });

            })
            .error(function(data) {

                window.alert('Something Wrong...');
    });
    };

    $http.get(URLOperation, $scope)
        .success(function(data) {

            var groups = data;


           // console.log(groups.lenght);
            angular.forEach(groups, function(group) {
                var group2 = group;
               // $scope.groups = group;
                $scope.grupos.push(group);
                //console.log(group2);
               // console.log(group2.groupname);
                //console.log(group2.length)
            angular.forEach(group2.sites, function(group3){
                //console.log(group3.siteaddress);
                //console.log($scope.objects);
$scope.longitud.push(group3);
                $scope.objects.push(group3);

                $scope.predicate = 'msisdn';
                $scope.reverse = true;
                $scope.order = function(predicate) {
                    $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
                    $scope.predicate = predicate;
                };

            })

            });

        })
        .error(function(data) {

            window.alert('Something Wrong...');
        });

    $scope.logout = function() {

        $http.get(URL)
            .success(function() {
                window.alert('Cerrando Sesión ');

                window.location.href='/index.html';
            })
            .error(function(data) {

                window.alert('No se ha podido cerrar la sesión');
            });
    };

    $scope.password = {};
    $scope.changepassword = function() {

        $http.post(URL,$scope.signup)
            .success(function(data) {
                window.alert('Bienvenido ' + data.result.username + 'última vez que iniciaste sesión fue el '+ data.result.lastlogin);
                //$window.localStorage.token = data;
                window.location.href='/Dashboard.html';
            })
            .error(function(data) {

                window.alert('Wrong credetianls');
            });
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's the attribute ContractingMode that you want to change, you can do something like that:

```
<td>{{object.ContractingMode ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}</td>
```